# Win32com locating time of email after restricting timeframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, win32com

I would like to capture the date/time when a message was sent so that I can store the info in dataframe. I have connected to my inbox and can extract the email and I have restricted the time so that I can only get emails from the last 7 days.

Here's my code:

```
import win32com.client as wc
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt



last_week = dt.date.today()- dt.timedelta(days = 7)
last_week = last_week.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p')


#Search through my inbox
outlook = wc.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
mapi = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

root_folder = mapi.Folders['username'].Folders['Inbox'].Folders['folder']
print(root_folder.Name)

#restrict inbox to 7 days
messages = root_folder.Items
messages = messages.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" + last_week + "'")
messages.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", True)

#grab message and convert to pandas DF. Expected 7 messages
counter = 0
for message in messages:
    if message.Subject == 'Message_1':
        print(counter, message.Subject)
        print(messages.SentOn) ### I Get my Attributes Error here :(
        html_str = message.HTMLBody
        get_table = pd.read_html(html_str)[0]
        counter += 1
```

When I added the **SentOn** Method I am getting an AttributeError saying "Restrict.SentOn" I am assuming that this is because I have restricted my time period.

How do I get the actual date/time of the individual message?

Comment: Should be `message.SentOn`? Typo?

Comment: oh my goodness!! Thats all it was :)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use the individual object as the item to get the .SentOn info from